# mysql query truncated after increasing 'max_allowed_packet'

Tags: c#, mysql

I have a stored procedure in c# that I add values to and then execute:

```
        string query = "INSERT INTO equipment_parameter (parameter_group_name, version, operation_name, parameter_name, parameter_value, default, owner, date_created) VALUES(@parameter_group_name, @version, @operation_name, @parameter_name, @parameter_value, @default, @owner, @date_created)";    //stored procedure

        //open connection
        if (mySQLA.OpenConnection() == true)
        {
            //create command  
            MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = mySQLA.getConnection();
            cmd.CommandText = query;
            cmd.Prepare();

            //string
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_group_name", eParam.ParameterGroupName);
            //int 
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@version", eParam.Version);
            //string
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@operation_name", eParam.OperationName);
            //string
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_name", eParam.ParameterName);
            //double
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@parameter_value", eParam.ParameterValue);
            //bool
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@default", eParam.Default);
            //string
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owner", eParam.Owner);
            //DateTime
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date_created", eParam.DateCreated);

            //Execute command
            try
            {
                rowsCreated = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();      //returns number of rows affected
            }
            catch (MySqlException es)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(es.Message, "Equipment Parameter Query Error: ");
            }
```

When I run this program it attempts the insertion and then I catch the exception which states:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'default, owner, date_created) VALUES('object1', 1, 'Op1', 'object1', 10.01, 1, '' at line 1
```

The query I'm trying to execute would read something like:

```
INSERT INTO equipment_parameter (parameter_group_name, version, operation_name, parameter_name, parameter_value, default, owner, date_created) VALUES('object', 1, 'Op1', 'object1', 10.01, false, 'James', '2013-10-30 09:00:54')
```

I have already increased 'max_allowed_packet' to 500M and restarted the server though this had no effect.  Are there other buffer-size options I can increase or what may be my problem?

Comment: Unrelated: You don't need the `== true` part at all, by the way, it is superflous.

Comment: Can you output the complete query that you're trying to execute with the values set? Also, can you provide the data types of each of the columns in that table? And finally, why did you mark up there `stored procedure`?

Comment: I've added the query I'm attempting to execute at the bottom, I've also commented the data types for each column above the respective "addWithValue" command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After boiling my head with this I've just realised that `default` is a reserved word. As such, it has to be backticked:

```
[...] parameter_value, `default`, owner, date_created) [...]
```

Comment: Should have realized that after it was highlighted in blue in my question.  You're amazing!

Comment: My only question now is why was it truncating the query if it was just the parameter name tripping it up?

Comment: I guess you mean in the error you got from MySQL. It was not truncating the query, it was just selecting the part of it that couldn't process. It doesn't usually help much but in this case it did as it just started after the `default` word. Another thing to mention is that the query never actually got to be executed as it contained syntactical errors.